# Почему не работает пропс VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Создан компонент который должен принимать пропс, у пропса есть дефолтное значение.

При попытке передать в пропс `true`, ничего не меняется, значение так же остаётся `false`.

В чём может быть дело?
Пробовал не задавать дефолтное значение

```
Vue.component('configurator', {
    props: {
        isLoading: {
          default: false
        }
    },
    template: '<div>{{ isLoading }}</div>' // <- Тут false, а должно быть true
})
```

,

```
<configurator :isLoading="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[При использовании шаблона в DOM, применяется kebab-case конвертация имен пропсов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-camelCase-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-kebab-case). Поэтому, в данном случае, указанное значение не попадает в пропс.

То есть, надо в шаблоне изменить формат имени пропса (атрибута директивы `v-bind`) с camelCase на kebab-case:
`:isLoading="true"`  `:is-loading="true"`